# Two forms share same input

Tags: html, forms, input

How can two forms share the same inputs?
I have two forms, one for two different paths... if i wanted to get the user to enter their name, but only once.... how could both forms get hold on this field?

Comment: For those curious, the [`form` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-form) can only specify one form. It  cannot be used for this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using JavaScript you could set one field's value to another's.

Something like:

```
document.form2.input.value = this.value;
```

Put that code in the onblur event for your first form.

So:

```
<form name="form1">
<input type="text" name="input" onblur="document.form2.input.value = this.value;" />
</form>

<form name="form2">
<input type="text" name="input" onblur="document.form1.input.value = this.value;" />
</form>
```

Comment: was hoping to do this without JS but what they hey :)

Comment: Unfortunately there is no other way, I've edited my post to include a copy-paste example.

Comment: Hold on. The [w3schools textarea page](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp) says (in a simplified way) `Element=textarea, Attribute=form, Value=form_id, Description="Specifies one or more forms the text area belongs to"` Why isn't it possible to specify a list of forms? It would solve my current problem a lot @WaleedAmjad

Answer (score 30):

In `HTML5` you could do it without `JavaScript`.
Do one form with one set of inputs, and just make two submit buttons using a different **formaction** attributes [found on Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-formaction)
like this:

```
<form>
    <input name="fname" type="text" />

    <input type="submit" value="button one" formaction="script_one.php">
    <input type="submit" value="button two" formaction="script_two.php">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're working with go and the above examples aren't good enough try the below combination of java and html. Inside your HTML file add the following script inside it, then use a form called Form1 to trigger an action to the page you want base on the button.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function OnButton1()
    {
        document.Form1.action = "/first_page.html"  
        document.Form1.submit()
    }

function OnButton2()
    {
        document.Form1.action = "/second_page.html"
        document.Form1.submit()                 
    }
</script>
<body>
<form name="Form1" method="POST">

    Your Name <input type="text" name="text1" value="">

    <button type="submit" value="Button1" name="button1" onclick="return OnButton1();">Button1<button>
    <button type="submit" value="Button2" name="button2" onclick="return OnButton2();">Button2<button>
    
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late reply, but I found the thread looking for an answer, so...

@CharlieG had a suggestion that should get more merit, despite the comment from @4castle which is only partially correct (you CAN only specify one form... at a time).

You can change an input's form association dynamically with javascript using .setAttribute.

```
document.getElementById("SharedInput").setAttribute("form","form_" + TabName);
```

For example, I use this with a page with multiple "tabs" that has some common information between them.