# Submit doesn't work on this form

Tags: jquery

Whenever I hit submit for paypal or credit card on this form, it always goes to the AlertPay checkout page. Why is that? I'm trying to give multiple checkout and payment options so buyers can use what they have if they don't have one of the other options. Here's my code.

```
<form action="http://c.uhelios.com/alert_process.php" method="POST" id="paypal-payment-form">
        <input type='hidden' name='stripePackage' value='' id='stripePackage_id_pp' />
        <input type='hidden' name='stripeName' value='' id='stripeName_id_pp' />
        <input type='hidden' name='stripeEmail' value='' id='stripeEmail_id_pp' />
        <input type='hidden' name='stripeUDID' value='' id='stripeUDID_id_pp' />
<form action="http://c.uhelios.com/paypal_process.php" method="POST" id="paypal-paypal-payment-form">
        <input type='hidden' name='stripePackage' value='' id='stripePackage_id_pp_' />
        <input type='hidden' name='stripeName' value='' id='stripeName_id_pp_' />
        <input type='hidden' name='stripeEmail' value='' id='stripeEmail_id_pp_' />
        <input type='hidden' name='stripeUDID' value='' id='stripeUDID_id_pp_' />
<!-- Presets -->
<div id="errors" style="color:#C00; text-align:center;">Errors: None</div>
<form id="store-form-fields" action="" method="post">
<p>
<span class="input-container">
<input type="text" name="Name" id="fullname_id" value="Name" class="required" tabindex="1" />
</span>
<span class="input-container">
<input type="text" name="E-mail" id="email_field" value="E-mail Address" class="require email” tabindex="2" />
</span>
<span class="input-container">
<input type="text" name="UDID" id="udid_field" value="UDID" class=""  tabindex="3" />
</span></p>
<p> <span class="input-container1"> <select id="package_list">
<option value="Siri Server" selected="selected">Siri Server $15.00 USD</option>
</select> </span>
<span class="input-container1"> <select name="device">
    <option value="iPhone (3G, 4, 4S)">iPhone (3G, 3GS, 4, 4S) </option>
    <option value="iPad (2)">iPad/iPad 2 </option>
    <option value="iPod Touch (2G, 3G, 4G)">iPod Touch (2G, 3G, 4G) </option>
</select> </span>

</p>                            
<p>
<input name="message-submit" id="paypal-submit" type="submit" onclick="verify3();" value="" tabindex="4" />
</p> 
<p>
<input name="message-submit" id="alertpay-submit" type="submit" onclick="verify2();" value="" tabindex="5"/>
</p> 
<p>
<input name="message-submit" id="creditcard-submit" type="submit" onclick="verify();" value="" tabindex="6" />
</p>                                     
</form></form>
```

Comment: That is way, _way_ more code than belongs in an SO question. How about trimming it down to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: Trim this down to the minimum possible number of lines that demonstrates the problem. Not only will that make it easy to someone to answer, you are likely to find the solution yourself.

Comment: Why do you have two form tags?

Comment: Before anything else, un-nest your forms. Nested forms will give unpredictable behaviour, including the sort of thing you report. Also balance them - 5 x <form>, 4 x </form>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close the first form tag before the second one.

Comment: When I add </form> code to the end of each form, it just refreshes the page when I submit.

Comment: I see what you're trying to accomplish.  You are trying to share the same inputs with multiple forms.  This question should of use to you then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692564/two-forms-share-same-input